# How can I tell when an Album is added to the MediaStore

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to run some code every time an Album is added to Android MediaStore db. I guess I need to register my app for an intent but not sure which one. Anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close, but you register to listen for changes to the MediaStore content URI. Something like this, for instance, probably implemented in a service:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, 
    new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.d("ScratchService","External Media has been added");
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }
    }
);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, 
    new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.d("ScratchService","Internal Media has been added");
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }
    }
);
```

This will only tell you when the MediaStore has been changed, it won't tell you what's been added or deleted. For that you'll have to query the MediaStore.

I hope that's of some use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it seems to be triggered all the time, even when I dont think any audio is being updated (could be when audio is read). Im using the Uri MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. The huge number of onChange events coupled with not even knowing which audio was modified makes it quite a computationally expensive service to run. In your experience did onchange get triggered a lot?

Comment: I'm afraid the only direct experience I have of this is the small service I wrote to test the above, but I'll bet you're right that it's being updated whenever audio is read. I just tried it again with android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and I'm only getting notifications when albums are added and deleted (oddly enough, both are being fired). Is that closer to your needs?

Comment: I tried that too but this solution still wasnt ideal for me. I ended up going for a polling solution in conjunctions with listening to MEDIA_SCAN_FINISHED.