# How to capture taking screenshot by volumn down and power keys on android?

Tags: android, screenshot

From android 4.0+, it supports to take screenshot by pressing volumn down+power keys. I'm going to use the screenshot image immediately when after taking screenshot by the hotkey.

Is there any Android SDK API to be used as a callback of the event? then I can register such listener to the event of taking screenshot.

Will taking screenshot by vol down+power send some public broadcast? then I can receive this public broadcast.

Is there any way to capture hotkey events? When pressing volumn down+power at the same time, can I get a notification?

Comment: which phone are you using? I know xperia arc s uses volume down + power, but s2 and note are using menu + volume down instead.

Comment: I want the app to support most of phones.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Android SDK API to be used as a callback of the event?

Not specifically. You could try listening for events related generally to changes in available image content (e.g., a `ContentResolver` on `MediaStore`), but that will cover other things, such as pictures taken by the camera.

> Is there any way to capture hotkey events?

You are welcome to see if `onKeyDown()` of a foreground activity hears about this event, though I doubt it. And if your activity is not in the foreground, you definitely cannot hear about this event.

Comment: I guess this kind of operation should send broadcast, do you know about it? I tried to listen for changes on screenshot directory on sdcard, but not know how to monitor MediaStore and ContentResolver. Could you explain more clearly? thank you very much

Comment: @user1693380: "I guess this kind of operation should send broadcast, do you know about it?" -- I am not aware of a broadcast for a screenshot. "but not know how to monitor MediaStore and ContentResolver" -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116693/how-can-i-tell-when-an-album-is-added-to-the-mediastore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230643/android-api-for-detecting-new-media-from-inbuilt-camera-mic